# Reactjs : TypeError: Cannot read property 'propTypes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

Please i am asked to write a unitTest for the following reactjs page.

```
export default class Collapsible extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        title: React.PropTypes.string,
        children: React.PropTypes.any,
    };

    render() {
        const { title } = this.props;
        return (
            <details>
                <summary>{title}</summary>
                {this.props.children}
            </details>
        );
    }
}
```

Following the tut [Here](https://blog.algolia.com/how-we-unit-test-react-components-using-expect-jsx/) I wrote my test below like

```
describe('Collapsible', ()=>{
    it('works', ()=>{
        let renderer = createRenderer();
        renderer.render(<Collapsible title="MyTitle"><span>HEllo</span></Collapsible>);
        let actualElement = renderer.getRenderOutput();
        let expectedElement = (<details><summary>title</summary>Details</details>);
        expect(actualElement).toEqual(expectedElement);                     
    });
});
```

However, my test is throwing the error in the title above, i am suspecting my props on the Collapsible (i.e title and children) are not assigning from the test . Please how do i address this? Any help or guidance would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for your time all. It turns out i was importing the Collapsible in to the test file wrongly . Below is how i was importing before

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'expect';
import {createRenderer} from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import { Collapsible }  from '../Collapsible.js';
```

After changing to

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'expect';
import {createRenderer} from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import Collapsible  from '../Collapsible';
```

It seems to work. I was importing Collapsible as an existing variable/object before. After reading through docs and few tutorials i realised .

Comment: In my case it was the other way around - I added redux's `connect()` method and exported with different name. Forgot to change it in tests.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes), one way to define props with ES6 classes is as follows:

```
export default class Collapsible extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { title } = this.props;
        return (
            <details>
                <summary>{title}</summary>
                {this.props.children}
            </details>
        );
    }
}

Collapsible.propTypes = {
    title: React.PropTypes.string,
    children: React.PropTypes.any,
};
```

Comment: thanks for the response. We use the component and is working fine. I encounter the isssue while implementing the unitTest above. I am suspecting the error is in the way i pass my props in the uniTest file above. However, i am not sure where and how to fix this .